# difference between 死, 死ぬ, & 死去?

Tags: kanji-choice

How are 死{し}, 死ぬ{しぬ}, & 死去{しきょ} different? Is it "die" vs "to die"?

Comment: What differences are you trying to understand? Semantic differences? Word class? Can you be more specific?

Comment: as in noun vs verb, are there differences in tense?　I think 死ぬ is a verb, but I'm not sure about the other 2.

Comment: Related:  [What are the nuances between 死亡 and 死去?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51744/78)

Answer (score 2):

`死` [し] is a noun meaning 'death'. It can also be a noun suffix (～死) where the stem gives more information about the death. For example, 事故死 [じこし] (accident+death = accidental death).

`死ぬ`[しぬ] is a godan verb meaning 'to die' (病気で死ぬ to die from disease)

`死去`[しきょ] is a verbal noun meaning 'death'. Verbal nouns are words which can act as standalone nouns or can be combined with する to become verbs and take on verbal meanings (死去する to die).

Standard dictionaries provide information on word-class and meanings. For example, check [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%AD%BB%E3%81%AC) and you will notice "Godan verb with nu ending, Irregular nu verb, intransitive verb" included with the definition.